# Django Simple Template Tag Questions

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm a student who is learning how to play Django. You are about to output a p-tag using template tags in the vault. The template tag I want to use is "When option.product_code and product.product_code are the same in the Option table, print out if there are two options.option_code". How should I fill out the if statement?

I'd like to add

Hello

by referring to the above. Please give me some advice.

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Option(models.Model):
    option_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['option_code']
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
        products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('option_set').annotate(noption=Count('option_set'))


    return render(request, 'option/option_list.html', {'products':products})
```

****templates****

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% for option in product.option_set.all %}
            {% if product.noption >= 2 %}

<p> hello! </p>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

**ERROR :**

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'option_set' into field. Choices are: product_code, name, option
```

Comment: This does *not* belong to the template, but to the *view*. Please share the related models and view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Option tables include option_code, optionn_name, product_code.
The product table contains product_code product_name, image. The product_code of Option has a product called 'hat' registered, and the option_name has two registered products, size and color. 

View에서는 product = Product.objects.all()
Option.objects.all() This is all.
I just want to put the p-tag in that condition.

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've edited the content. Thank you for watching.

Comment: This is an example of Django being "opinionated". If you want to put complex logic in templates (different opinion) you can still use Django, but you will want to use it with the Jinja template engine. (Personally I think the Django developers' opinion is right a lot more often than not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do the joining in the template. Templates implement *rendering logic*, not *business logic*. You can enumerate over the related `Option`s of a product with:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
    {% for option in product.option_set.all %}
        option: {{ option.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the view you thus should only pass the `products` (not <s>`product`</s>, since it is a *collection* of `Product`s), and by using [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) you can prevent making *N+1* queries:

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('option_set')
    return render(
        request,
        'option/option_list.html',
        {'products': products)
    )
```

Comment: You are a really cool developer. thank you. I'll try running it the way you told me. thank you. There is one more thing I want to ask you,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652095/please-see-if-it-is-possible-to-print-various-options-no-code-during-the-imple

I'm curious to know if the answer I asked in this link is feasible.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, but as you said, there is no problem enumerating product-related options. But what I want to implement is to display the <p> tag only when there are two or more options in one product_code. What should I do?

Comment: @roboca: you can annotate the `Product`s with a condition, so `Product.objects.annotate(noption=Count('option_set')).prefetch_related('option_set')`, then you can work with `{% if product.noption >= 2 %}` in the template (in the `{% for ... %}`) loop.

Comment: The .annotate(noption=Count('option_set') indicates that option_set is not found. product.objects say option_set is not found. I'm so sad. I'd appreciate it if you could see if there's a problem with the history I modified. I added it to the body.

Comment: @roboca: then you need to `Count('option')`